# how to use trigger in a way to have all updated columns of base table to multiple rows of audit table?

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, database-trigger

I am trying to insert old and new values of 'Base' table into auditing table 'Audit'.
 Problem is in requirement of how data to be stored in Audit table.
If more then one columns are updated I should be able to store it in this format.

Structure of 'Audit' table

```
Id | Column_Name | Old_Value | New_Value
 1 | Strike      | 4         | 5
 2 | Spare       | 3         | 7
 3 | Score       | 10        | 18
```

My solution gives following structure

```
Id | old_strike | new_strike | old_spare | new_spare | old_score | new_score
1  | 4          | 5          | 3         | 7         | 10        | 18
```

I've tried this using trigger to save old and new value in a rows but having hard time in figuring out how to traverse for single insert statement for each columns.

````
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON frame  -- after event
FOR EACH ROW    // fires for each record
BEGIN

INSERT INTO frame_audit(bowler_id,game_id,frame_number,
old_strike,new_strike,
old_spare,new_spare,
old_score,new_score,
change_date,operation)

VALUES(:NEW.bowler_id,:NEW.game_id,:NEW.frame_number,
:OLD.strike,:NEW.strike,
:OLD.spare,:NEW.spare,
:OLD.score,:NEW.score,
SYSDATE,'UPDATE');
END audit_frames```

// Structure of 'Audit' table
Id | Column_Name | Old_Value | New_Value
 1 | Strike      | 4         | 5
 2 | Spare       | 3         | 7
 3 | Score       | 10        | 18
````

Comment: There's no option to read old/new values of columns dynamically and you must explicitly insert rows for all columns

Comment: One row per column is a familiar auditing anti-pattern. It seems sensible but it's a performance nightmare. Update one row in the table insert three rows in the audit? Mare. Ten column table so ten inserts? Mare. Just audit the columns which have changed? Good luck re-assembling the record's change history. Another 'mare. But if you're wedded to the structure make sure your AUDIT table has TRANSACTION_ID column to identified all the rows for one changes. Otherwise you'll never be able to reconstruct the record's state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned over comments, There's no option to fetch `OLD` and `NEW` values specific to each column name dynamically. All you could do is to write explicit inserts  for all the columns with hardcoded column names.

```
 ...
 ...

BEGIN


INSERT INTO frame_audit (Id ,Column_Name , Old_Value , New_Value)
SELECT  audit_seq.nextval,'bowler_id',old.bowler_id,new.bowler_id 
FROM DUAL WHERE 
 (    old.bowler_id <> new.bowler_id OR
      (old.bowler_id is NULL     and new.bowler_id is NOT NULL) OR
      (old.bowler_id is NOT NULL and new.bowler_id is NULL   ) 
 );

INSERT INTO frame_audit (Id ,Column_Name , Old_Value , New_Value)
SELECT  audit_seq.nextval,'game_id',old.game_id,new.game_id 
FROM DUAL WHERE 
 (    old.game_id <> new.game_id OR
      (old.game_id is NULL     and new.game_id is NOT NULL) OR
      (old.game_id is NOT NULL and new.game_id is NULL   ) 
 );

--similar inserts for all other columns


 ...

END;
```

Here I'm assuming you have a sequence created to generate ids for Audit table.

You may simplify the lengthy `NULL` check expression using `NVL` or `COALESCE`, but you should use it as per the data type of each column. If the column is defined as `not null`, a simple `<>` check would be sufficient. For `DATE/TIMESTAMP` related columns, you would need to use `TO_CHAR` if you want to store it in a desired format.